# Javascript Object required error when calling value of hidden field

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, object-expected

Code:
Html:

```
<input type="hidden" id="lblHierarchyType" value="" runat="server" />
```

C# Codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lblHierarchyType.Value == "")
        {
            lblHierarchyType.Value = "AOR";
        }
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            txtUserID.Focus();
            FillGroupsList();
            FillOrgTree();
            ClearErrorMsgs();
        }           
    }
```

Javascript:

```
        function populateSelectedNode(node) {
            debugger
            var selectedOrg = node.getValue();
            var hierarchyType = document.getElementById("lblHierarchyType").value;
        }
```

The code errors out (Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required) when it hits the assignment of lblHierarachy.value to var hierarchy.

Thanks

Comment: view the source of your page and make sure the input id IS rendering as lblHierarchyType, especially if you have a master page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ID that ASP.NET will generate will not be "lblHierarchyType" so better to change it by its ClientID

```
 var hierarchyType = document.
                   getElementById("<%= lblHierarchyType.ClientID%>").value;
```

Comment: You should note that anytime a `runat="server"` is added to an element, ASP.NET will generate a ClientID based on the page template hierarchy.

Comment: @todd.pund if this answer solved your problem please mark on the left as having answered your question